# How should I use this Seven Segment Optical Character Recognition ?

Tags: ocr

I found this online to solve a Digit number recognition issue I'm working on : https://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~auerswal/ssocr/

however I really don't have any clue how to use it. Can someone help me ?

It's written "Use `ssocr -T` to recognize the above image.". I don't understand.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You should install all the dependencies first in order to use this package. Check the prerequisite part in the Install file and install all necessary items. Try referring this [Raspberry Pi: Reading 7-Segment Displays](http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Reading-7-Segment-Displays/) guide for installation.